# How to use AngularJS files in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am developing an app in Angular 2. But certain features like TinyMCE and Froala editor are implemented only in AngularJS.

I would need to refer these packages into my Angular 2 app. I did refer to the examples that they had provided, but none of them explained how to import AngularJS packages into Angular 2 Typescript.

I am using Visual Studio to develop my app. How could I solve this problem?

---

**EDIT:** Tried referring  by `var tinymce = require('/app/scripts/tinymce/tinymce.js');` only to get more errors that says `tinymce.init is not a function`

Any help or advice is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you Google this at all? Because e.g. https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/. It will depend on how you're managing your project (webpack, system.js, etc.).

Comment: system.js is how the project is being managed. Yes. I did google it, but couldn't find how to do it.

Comment: What did you find? What have you tried? What happened?

Comment: Got more errors that kept telling that `tinymce.init is not a function`. Have edited that into the question.